# multiple horizontally aligned input boxes with vertically aligned labels underneath

Tags: forms, alignment

I want to create a form similar to [this one.](http://coachpacman.wufoo.com/forms/untitled-form/)

In particular, I want to learn how to put different sized input boxes on the same line with vertically aligned labels underneath. For instance, in the "Name" section of the form, it has a box for "first" and "last."

How can you do this with HTML and CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You sample form contains SPAN elements with `display` property set to `inline-block`, and the INPUT and LABEL elements each have a display property value of `block`, with a fixed size. That way, you are basically creating cells to contain your elements and their labels.

The same thing could be achieved using TABLE/TR/TD combination, though it would be a little old-fashioned, and thus not recommended.

Comment: No problem. You're welcome. :) I hope you can come back and contribute to the community.